# How can I terminate a process of an external application created by a QT Process?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm working in the implementation of a new feature in an existing application. I have a class that inherits from QProcess. In the run method, an external application is executed with `start("C:\Apss\bin\myAplication.bat", parameters);`

I have the destructor for an object of type Qwidget, so when the destructor is executed the external application should close as well, however the external application process still running.

I tried with:

```
p->terminate();
p.waitForFinished(10000);
```

Also I tried with some variants like:

```
p->kill();
p.waitForFinished(-1);
```

But it doesn't seem to work.
I tried to use `system("taskkill /im myApllication.exe /f");` and it terminates the process running in te background. The problem is that sometimes I have more than one process of the external application running, so when I use `system("taskkill /im myApllication.exe /f");` all the process are terminated and I get the following:

```
SUCCESS: The process "myAplication.exe" with PID 16708 has been terminated;
SUCCESS: The process "myAplication.exe" with PID 2120 has been terminated;
```

but this is not the desired behavior, because I want to close only the process created in the current QProcess execution. There is a way to terminate only the process created by the current QTprocess?.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: _"sometimes I have more than one process of the external application running"_ - Do you also have a container with all the `QProcess` objects you need to `kill` or `terminate` them? If `p->kill()` doesn't seem to work, I think that `p` is pointing at a `QProcess` that has already finished.

Comment: No, In My GUI aplication I can simulate a terminal. I create the terminal with a QWidget and When the Qwidget is created a process of  the .exe is also created. So, I want to create/open múltiple terminals. But when I close the terminal I want to force the quit of the process of the current terminal, not all the procesess.

Comment: So, the `QWidget` owns a `QProcess` and you have a container with all your `QWidget`s? Who owns `p`? Who owns the owner of `p`?